# What's the best and most efficient book to learn JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

What's the best and most efficient book to learn JavaScript?

Comment: If depends on how you learn. Some learn best by reading examples, some want to know the theory up front while some just like to dive in and try stuff out. On that basis, I'd say the question (or at least the answers) are subjective.

Comment: why do people insist on having "the best" in their title?

Comment: Because we all deserve the best, Geo ;).  To keep going with what Colin was saying, not only does how you learn matter, but your background and as well.  There are some decent books that are good for designers who want to learn JavaScript, but those same books are atrocious for people with any programming background.

Comment: see duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74884/good-javascript-books

Comment: best : Professional JavaScript for Web Developers, 3rd Edition

Comment: You may follow these JavaScript Tutorials - https://www.tutorialkart.com/javascript/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think I've read them all. Here's the dark sheep. This one came out of left field. I was surprised at how good it is.

[JavaScript: The Missing Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596515898)

[alt text http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51cPJ2k%2BOGL._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA240_SH20_OU01_.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51cPJ2k%2BOGL._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA240_SH20_OU01_.jpg)

The other books are great. But for actually *learning* the language, I think this one wins hands down.

Comment: +1 looks good! Just bought it :)

Answer (score 28):

Take a look at [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805531.do).

Also take a look at [David Flanagan's web site](http://www.davidflanagan.com/) as well as [Douglas Crockford's videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7664379246A246CB) and [his essays on JavaScript](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/).

Comment: I think it's a great reference book, but I give it a "meh" on teaching you the language.

Comment: It's not a book, but I found Crockford's essays a great help: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/

Comment: I was always mystified by JavaScript (not that I am expert now) until I read Flanagan's book. I found Crockford's essays more useful than the "Good Parts" book.

Comment: FYI: There is a 6th edition of Javascript: The definitive guide.

Comment: The only book Crockford himself recommends is `JavaScript: The Definitive Guide` by `David Flanagan` on his website: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/javascript.html

Answer (score 16):

[JavaScript the good parts.](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748/)

Comment: have the book, it doesn't offer a complete intro though, so if you see a "bad part" somewhere, you might not know what it does. Its about 1/10 the size of the definitive guide, and only covers the language, not any interaction with the browser. great supplemental book though. :D

Comment: My favorite JavaScript book, but for learning, go with "The Missing Manual" first.

Comment: i read The Good Parts as my very first javascript book, and it helped me keep good practices in mind when reading other books, so I would actually recommend this as a first (but not only) JS book

Comment: @Douglas are you self promoting your book? :)

Comment: @GordonGustafson, The only book Crockford himself recommends is `JavaScript: The Definitive Guide` by `David Flanagan` on his website: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/javascript.html

Answer (score 5):

after the basics, every Javascript developer **must** read this: 
[Douglas Crockford: JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)

Answer (score 3):

[ppk on JavaScript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321423305) was really great. His [website](http://www.quirksmode.org/) is also filled with tons of useful information including lots on browser incompatibilities.

[image]

Comment: This book got me started. I thought it wasn't overly technical or dry and gave some practical advice.

Answer (score 3):

After you've tried out some of the books, read them through, make sure you try many things and ideas out on your own. The only way to really learn a language is to write programs in it. After you have a good understanding, answer some questions on SO. This can really help you learn stuff and have fun talking code with other people. An SO technique I use is to find a user with 20k + rep who has a lot of posts in the javascript tag, then look at some of their most upvoted javascript answers. Good luck! :D

Answer (score 2):

i would recommend "[Head First JavaScript](http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/0596527748?ie=UTF8&tag=shopnetwork0d-21&linkCode=as2&camp=1638&creative=19454&creativeASIN=0596527748)" it is nice to read, with good illustrations. I love the books from this publisher.

Answer (score 2):

[Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847194141)

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend [Pro JavaScript Techniques: The Ultimate JavaScript book for the modern Web Developer](http://jspro.org/) by By John Resig, the author of jQuery framework.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript: The Good Parts

[http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)

Answer (score 1):

Learning Javascript: [http://www.amazon.com/Learning-JavaScript-Shelley-Powers/dp/0596527462/ref=sr_1_16?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1247773699&sr=8-16](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596527462)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a believer in Sinan's recommendation of JavaScript: The Definitive Guide for a good reference type book.

[Previous SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript)

[Another previous SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74884/good-javascript-books)

Answer (score 0):

Sams TEach yourself JavaScript Fourth Edition.
[Buy it really CHEAP here.](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_ss_b?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=0672328798&x=20&y=25)

Answer (score 0):

I like this one too much "[OReilly.JavaScript.The.Definitive.Guide.5th.Edition.Aug.2006](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101992/)"